# Hazelcast MapStore concurrency

Tags: java, hazelcast, persistence.xml

Looking at Hazelcast [Map Persistence article](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/map-persistence.html#map-persistence) and wondering: why MapStore methods are declared with **synchronized** keyword? 
Is there a chance that this method would be called concurrently for **same** record key?

Especially in case of write-through map store, when storage methods are called synchronously with IMap methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible that the `MapStore` implementation is called concurrently from different partitions. That said it means there'll never be a concurrent call for the same key but different keys.

In the example there is only a single database (SQL) connection and therefore all methods need to share the same mutex (which is enforced using the synchronized block). If you have, on the other side, a multi-threaded (thread-safe) database access / client or a connection pool you'll be fine to not synchronize access to the methods.